# Validate with TryUpdateModel in web service (asmx - asp.net web forms)?

Tags: model-binding

I want to validate a model in web service, so how can I do it?
Is it possible to validate object with TryUpdateModel in web service method?

```
public class MyEntity
{
    [Required]
    [StringLength(120, MinimumLength = 3)]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(120, MinimumLength = 3)]
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}

public bool ValidateEntity()
{
    MyEntity m = new MyEntity
    {
        FirstName = "ali",
        LastName = "amiri"
    };

    if (TryUpdateModel(MyEntity, new FormValueProvider(m)))
    {
        //....
    }
}
```